# how to disable more than one input text field?

Tags: javascript, html

how can I disable more than one input text field after clicking on submit button

html code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="YOUR NAME" id="name">   //first input text field
<input type="text" placeholder="YOUR NAME" id="name">  //second input text field
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

javascript code:

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
}
```

this code is working only for first input text field but not for second. I want to disable both.
PLEASE HELPPPP

Comment: use class selector instead of id!

Comment: convert id into class and use document.querySelectorAll(".name").forEach(input => input.disabled = true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ids` are unique. You cannot have two elements with same `id`. Instead use `querySelectorAll`.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

function myFunction() {
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.disabled = true;
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="YOUR NAME">   
<input type="text" placeholder="YOUR NAME">  
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

--Edit--

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

function myFunction() {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.disabled = true;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="YOUR NAME" id="name">
<input type="text" placeholder="YOUR NAME" id="name">
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

function myFunction() {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.disabled = true;
    input.style.background = "red"
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="YOUR NAME" id="name">
<input type="text" placeholder="YOUR NAME" id="name">
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: @sarasiddiqui - You need to select `textarea` element too. i:e `document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');` see edit.

Comment: @sarasiddiqui - If the answer solves your problem, mark it as accepted to indicate the problem has been resolved.

Comment: I have one more question.
after disabling input text field the background color change into grey. how can I change the background color of my choice?

Comment: @sarasiddiqui - You can add `css` styles to element by setting its `style` property. i:e `input.style.background`. I have edited the second example.